# c# How to get all windows using MainWindowHandle

Tags: c#, api

Take a look at this picture:[image]

This is how i got the handle of the window enclosed by black box.

```
          Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("TopazChat");
          foreach (Process p in processes)
          {  

              MessageBox.Show(p.MainWindowHandle.ToString());
              List<IntPtr> test = GetChildWindows(p.MainWindowHandle);
               foreach (IntPtr IGotIt in test)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("I got the child windows");
               }
          }
```

My question is: how to get the handle of the windows that was enclosed by red box?
and is there something wrong with my approach?

any suggestions? I just use that approach because it is the only one that is familiar to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That other window is another a top-level window in the same process that implements one of the visible windows in the app. This is an old Delphi 7 app which implements a hidden top-level window that is outside the visible window hierarchy. That hidden window is the one you have found, highlighted in black, with class name TApplication.

If I were you I would p/invoke a call to EnumWindows to get all the top level windows which will include the visible main windows for that app. This would be implemented in a very similar way to your GetChildWindows method.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I'll try it